# Best way to self study Compilers: Principles, Techniques & Tools

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm trying to study the book referenced in the title but am having a hard time.  Can anyone suggestion some tips?

Comment: If you prefer video lectures then this thread might be handy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424796/are-there-any-compiler-lectures-available-via-video

Comment: Tip: read from left to right.

Comment: Just slowly digest it. What better ways are there to truly learn a topic anywaysh?

Answer (score 2):

Before studing above book, I think it is better to go through [Language Implementation Patterns: Create Your Own Domain-Specific and General Programming Languages](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns)  book.

It gives some basic idea about how a compiler/interpreter works. With that bascground you can easily study Dragon book.